# Why image pixels should be tiled in the WORD unit in the memory?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I am now reading the source code of [leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/highlevel.html#BASIC_PIX), which is a great document image processing and analysis library. In this library, it contains a basic image structure `Pix`, which is used to represent the image. In this structure, it has a variable to define how many WORD (one WORD is equal to 4 bytes) we should keep for pixels in each image horizontal line, and the definition is as follows:

```
 wpl = (width * depth + 31) / 32;
```

where `depth` referes to how many bits a pixel contains. For example, for the gray scale image, its pixel's depth is 8 while for color image its pixel's depth is 24.

Then the memory that should be allocated for the image pixels becomes:

```
4 * wpl * height;
```

For me, I cannot understand why the pixels should be tiled in the memory in this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a bitmap representation of an image, a single image is usually represented by a block of bytes (words) in sequence. If you use a row-major ordering then you can also treat it as a two dimensional array, and index it like `arr[row][col]` if you cast it to the appropriate array type (in `C` code for instance).

If `depth` is the number of bits for a single pixel, `width * depth` is the number of bits for a whole row.

Then, `(width * depth + 31) / 32`, in integer arithmetic, is the smallest number of 32 bit blocks needed in order to hold that row.

(Note that the `+31` is there to enforce that we round up in case `width * depth` is not cleanly divisible. In general `x / n` will round down, in both `C` and `C++`, discarding the remainder. But, if we add `n - 1` before rounding as in the expression `(x + (n-1)) / n`, we ensure that if there is any nonzero remainder in `x / n` then it adds up, with the `n-1`, to one more multiple of `n` and then any remainder after that is discarded. So this is a way to round up rather than down in (unsigned) integer arithmetic.)

The number of 32 bit blocks needed for the whole image is then `wpl * height`. If we multiply by `4`, we get that `4 * wpl * height` is the number of 8 bit blocks (bytes) needed for the whole image.

Note that if the bit depth is much less than 32, for instance, if the depth is 8 like you were saying, this is actually going to be fairly inefficient, since you'll still get 32 bits per pixel even though you only need to use 8 of them. However, the most common format of bitmap images is 32 bit [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space), so in typical cases / for typical formats, there wouldn't be so much waste.

Comment: +1.  To address the "why" part of the question:  The 4-byte alignment requirement can make certain memory accesses faster, possibly enable the use of some vectorization opcodes, and provide a couple bits in "scanline" pointers for dirty implementation tricks.